# Rasberry Pi 2 analog inputs

Tags: temperature, analog-to-digital

I am a newbie with the Raspberry Pi.

I want to measure temperature from 16 sensors. Is it possible to have 16 analog inputs?

If not what controller should I use, I need something with web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Raspberry Pi for the webserver. You have a variety of programming lanugauges you could use, like Python, C/C++ even C# (in Linux using Mono) or Windows IoT.

It would be allot easier if you could use [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) - Which supports connecting allot of sensors (various types) typically using 4 wires  (2 power + 2 RX/TX for bidirectional communication) (or 3 wires if using a leech circuit) to the Raspberry Pi's I<sup>2</sup>C

---

You can also get sensors using the [1 Wire Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire), like the DS18B20. This only requires 3 wires (2 power - 1 RX) since all we are doing is reading data and used GPIO PIN 7. You then need to enable the device tree for 1-wire in `/boot/config.txt` by adding `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` and rebooting the Raspberry Pi. *You can also mix various sensors using 1-wire*

[image]

<sup>* [A nice tutorial and source of image](http://www.reuk.co.uk/Connect-Multiple-Temperature-Sensors-with-Raspberry-Pi.htm)</sup>

---

But if you have no choice but to use Analogue you could get a 16 channel multiplexer and connect that using a few digital pins to the Raspberry Pi. You can find those at any popular electronics shops and are pretty cheap, you shouldn't need to pay more than 5USD/3GBP for one of these. You still need to convert the output from the multiplexer SNG to digital though.

[image]

*The multiplexer works by setting the digital pin combination, to set the Analogue channel you would like to measure. So you cant have real-time measure of all 16 sensors at once, but you can switch between them pretty fast anyway and get possibly all 16 reading within 1 second, maybe faster.*

Comment: As I said I am knewbie with Raspberry and sensors. I don't have to use analog sensors if I can digital measure temperature please let me know how. I want cheap solution. I thought that there are only analog sensors.